# Correct rewrite paths for .htaccess file for silex?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, silex

I've just begun experimenting with [silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/). I'm following [the documentation](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/web_servers.html) and am confused which way to go with the .htaccess paths. Some background:

- I'm using WAMP for my dev webserver, with `mod_rewrite` enabled
- I have [the "slim" copy of Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/download) unzipped and copied to c:\wamp\www\silex\
- I have [the example hello world route](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/intro.html) in c:\wamp\www\silex\web\index.php
- I have an .htaccess file that lives in the *silex* directory

The .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /silex/web
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

If I go to **localhost/silex/web/hello/world**, I get a working "Hello world" page, which is great.

...but if I go to **localhost/silex/hello/world**, I get the silex error:

> No route found for "GET /silex/hello/world"

That error makes sense to me... but does this mean that "web/" must be included in all of the site's URLs? Is that normal for silex apps?

Some questions come to mind:

- Which directory should the .htaccess file be  in -- `silex/` or `silex/web/`? Are there any problems I might run into with having it in either spot?
- Should the `RewriteBase` go to `/silex` or `/silex/web`? (documentation vaguely says "/path/to/app"; to me that means /silex)

Answer (score 2):

Try this in `/silex/.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /silex/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ web/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: That seems to produce the same results as what I have above. Is there a reason why this is better?

Comment: Yes, in general `RewriteBase` should match the relative directory of the .htaccess.

Comment: For testing comment out `RewriteCond` line and try `localhost/silex/hello/world` URL again.

Answer (score 2):

The Silex example assumes that `web` directory is set as document root of the virtual host.

You should have one VHOST per application, e.g. `silex.local` with a document root set to `c:\wamp\www\silex\web`. Then use the `.htaccess` example from the Silex site and put it into `c:\wamp\www\silex\web\.htaccess`.

Comment: And keep in mind for htaccess files to work at all you have to allow overriding the default settings by adding AllowOverride all in a <Directory> directive in your virtual host file.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a DNS server use your local hosts file as a DNS :

### note:

Make sure you apache mod_rewrite is enabled.

1: Add this to your hosts file:

```
linux /etc/hosts
windows c:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

127.0.0.1   silex.local
```

2: Create a new virtual host ( i'm using apache ):

```
linux ( Centos )
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/silex/
    ServerName silex.local
</VirtualHost>

windows ( WAMP )
c:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.6\conf\httpd.conf

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot C:/wamp/www/silex/
    ServerName silex.local
</VirtualHost>
```

3: Restart apache

4: In your silex root folder create .htaccess file :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```